# Find missing values on the same column of two tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, compare, diff, missing-data

Suppose you have two tables in a SQL Server database with the same schema for both tables.  I want to compare a single column on both tables and find the values that are missing in table1 but are in table2.  I've been doing this manually in Excel with a macro after I've gotten a distinct list in each query, but it would be less work if I had a query.  How can I find the missing records via T-SQL?  I'd like to do this for the following data types: `datetime, nvarchar & bigint`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT [dbo].[table1].[column1]
FROM [dbo].[table1]
ORDER BY [dbo].[table1].[column1] DESC

SELECT DISTINCT [dbo].[table2].[column1]
FROM [dbo].[table2]
ORDER BY [dbo].[table2].[column1] DESC
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are several ways you can do this...

`LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t2.column1
FROM dbo.table2 t2
LEFT JOIN dbo.table1 t1
  ON t2.Column1 = t1.Column1
WHERE t1.Column1 IS NULL
```

`NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t2.column1
FROM dbo.table2 t2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM dbo.table1 t1
  WHERE t1.column1 = t2.column1
)
```

`NOT IN`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t2.column1
FROM dbo.table2 t2
WHERE t2.column1 NOT IN (
  SELECT t1.column1
  FROM dbo.table1 t1
)
```

There are some slight variations in the behavior and efficiency of these approaches... based mostly on the presence of `NULL` values in columns, so try each approach to find the most efficient one that gives the results you expect.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT DISTINCT [dbo].[table2].[column1]
FROM [dbo].[table2]
except
SELECT DISTINCT [dbo].[table1].[column1]
FROM [dbo].[table1]
```

All the values of column1 in Table2 that are not present in column1 of Table1

Answer (score 1):

basically, you can use `LEFT JOIN`.

`TableB` is set as the main table in this case. By joining it with `TableA` using `LEFT JOIN`, the the records that have no match on `TableA` a will still be in the result list but their values are *NULL*. So to filter out non matching records, add a filtering condition which only select records with *NULL* value on tableA.

```
SELECT  b.*
FROM    tableB b
        LEFT JOIN tableA a
            ON a.column1 = b.column1
WHERE   a.column1 IS NULL
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 0):

`SQL Server 2005` onwards you could use `Except`

```
SELECT DISTINCT [dbo].[table2].[column1]
FROM [dbo].[table2]
Except
SELECT DISTINCT [dbo].[table1].[column1]
FROM [dbo].[table1]
```